# Interact with external applications

Tags: python-3.x, textbox, output

i want to write a python script to output the results i get (from the script) to an outside textbox.
Like an other program's text box,or a webpage's search bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try flask if you want it to put it to a web page.

to setup your database ([sqlite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite) for example), use something like this:

```
# creating database

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = None

try:
    con = lite.connect('test.db')

    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE HELLOWORLD;')
    cur.execute('USE DATABASE HELLOWORLD;')
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE HELLOWORLD.MYDATA(ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CONTENT TEXT NOT NULL,);')

except lite.Error, e:
    print "Error %s:" % e.args[0]
    sys.exit(1)

finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
```

Then change your script so that it writes its result to this database (sqlite databases can be accessed by many processes according to their website, only one can write at a time though):

```js
# insert values into db
a = ['this is a triumph', 'im making a note here', 'huge success']
for el in a:
    cur.execute('insert into HELLOWORLD.MYDATA values (?)', el)
```

and then have flask serve those. for flask to see the db youll need to do some initial setup:

```python
# more copy pasta from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlite3/
import sqlite3
from flask import g

DATABASE = '/path/to/test.db'

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = connect_to_database()
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

but then you can serve that information to a browser (put on your prettiest css pants for this one):

```python
# check out the demo at http://flask.pocoo.org/ to see where this goes
@app.route('/')
def index():
    cur = get_db().cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT ALL FROM HELLOWORLD.MYDATA')

    return "<p>{}</p>".format(cur.fetchall())
```

Disclaimer, I just put this together in the past couple minutes, i didnt actually get to test out any of this yet. But this should definitely get you started.